# Error when arguments in lambda function are not passed in the specific order

Tags: python, lambda, pygame

I apologize for the long title, I will clear things up now. I am making a visualizer for the bubble sort algorithm and I am using pygame. Now in my `main_loop()` I call `sort_array` method which is another `.py` which takes `redraw()` as an argument so the process of sorting could be seen (not just the final result).
This is the part of the `main_loop()`:

```
new_list = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8]
run = True
while run:

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                BubbleSort.sort_array(lambda: new_list, redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), main_grid.bubble_list)

    redraw(main_grid.bubble_list)
```

And here is the `BubbleSort`:

```
class BubbleSort:

    swap_counter = 0

    @staticmethod
    def sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array):
        print("array", array)
        print("redraw", redraw)
        print("bubble_array", bubble_array)
        for i, element in enumerate(array):
            if i < array.index(array[-1]):
                if element > array[i+1]:
                    temp_element = array[i+1]
                    array[i+1] = element
                    array[i] = temp_element

                    bubble_array[i+1].set_bubble_number(element)
                    bubble_array[i].set_bubble_number(temp_element)

                    BubbleSort.swap_counter += 1
                    redraw()
        if BubbleSort.swap_counter > 0:
            BubbleSort.swap_counter = 0
            BubbleSort.sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array)

        redraw()
        return array
```

Now, when `redraw` is not the first argument, the `TypeError: "function object is not iterable"` occurs.
When I print these three arguments, I get the following result:

```
array <function main_loop.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001B6745F5EE8>
redraw None
bubble_array [<__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80148>, <__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80EC8>, <__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80FC8>, <__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80DC8>, <__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80D48>, <__main__.Bubbles object at 0x000001B675F80A88>]
```

Why is `redraw` `None`? The last one is what it supposed to be.
Now the interesting part, when argument order is like this `(redraw, array, bubble_array)` or `redraw` is the first argument everything runes fine.
Please explain me why this happens.

I can provide the whole code if needed, it is not very long.

EDIT: MRE

```
import pygame as pg 

pg.init()

clock = pg.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

WIN_W = 800
WIN_H = 800
window = pg.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H))

class BubbleSort:

    swap_counter = 0

    @staticmethod
    def sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array):
        print("array", array)
        print("redraw", redraw)
        print("bubble_array", bubble_array)
        for i, element in enumerate(array):
            if i < array.index(array[-1]):
                if element > array[i+1]:
                    temp_element = array[i+1]
                    array[i+1] = element
                    array[i] = temp_element

                    bubble_array[i+1].set_bubble_number(element)
                    bubble_array[i].set_bubble_number(temp_element)

                    BubbleSort.swap_counter += 1
                    redraw()
        if BubbleSort.swap_counter > 0:
            BubbleSort.swap_counter = 0
            BubbleSort.sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array)

        redraw()
        return array


class Bubbles:

    font = pg.font.SysFont("Arial", 25, True)

    def __init__(self, center, radius, width):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.width = width
        self.colour = pg.Color("Blue")
        self.text = ""

    def set_bubble_number(self, number):
        self.text = number

    def change_colour(self, colour_name):
        self.colour = pg.Color(f"colour_name".capitalize())

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.center

    def get_bubble_number(self):
        return self.number

    def get_bubble_rendered_text(self):
        return Bubbles.font.render(f"{self.text}", 1, (255, 255, 255))


class Grid:

    bubble_list = []

    def __init__(self, start_pos, radius, width, array):
        self.start_pos = start_pos
        self.radius = radius
        self.width = width
        self.array = array

    def create_bubbles(self):
        for i, element in enumerate(self.array):
            bubble = Bubbles((self.start_pos[0] + (i * self.radius*2.5), self.start_pos[1]), self.radius, self.width)
            bubble.set_bubble_number(element)
            Grid.bubble_list.append(bubble)


def redraw(array):

    window.fill(pg.Color("Grey"))
    for bubble in array:
        pg.draw.circle(window, bubble.colour, bubble.get_pos(), bubble.radius, bubble.width)
        window.blit(bubble.get_bubble_rendered_text(), (bubble.get_pos()[0]-bubble.radius/2+bubble.width, bubble.get_pos()[1]-bubble.radius/2-bubble.width))
    pg.display.update()
    pg.time.wait(100)

def main_loop():

    new_list = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8]
    main_grid = Grid((200, 400), 20, 5, new_list)
    main_grid.create_bubbles()
    print(type(main_grid.bubble_list))
    run = True
    while run:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    BubbleSort.sort_array(lambda: new_list, redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), main_grid.bubble_list)

        redraw(main_grid.bubble_list)


main_loop()

pg.quit()
```

Here is the example which results in mentioned `TypeError`. But if this line:

```
BubbleSort.sort_array(lambda: new_list, redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), main_grid.bubble_list)
```

is changed to:

```
BubbleSort.sort_array(lambda: redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), new_list, main_grid.bubble_list)
```

and of course the position of arguments in the `BubbleSort` class `sort_array` method, the code runs as expeted.

Comment: No it is not, `new_list = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8]` I will edit now, and everything works fine when the order of arguments is like I mentioned at the end. And I accidentally copied the working one for the main_loop, fixed now

Comment: `array()` not `array` ~ you are trying to treat a function like a list.

Comment: That makes sense, but I think it is not the case, because everything runs when `array` is at 2nd or 3rd position

Comment: Your example is far from into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see what actually below line means

```
sort_array(lambda: new_list, redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), main_grid.bubble_list)
```

1. `lambda: new_list` is the first argument of function call `sort_array`. It is an anonymous function which returns `new_list` when executed. So a function is being passed to `sort_array` as first argument.
2. Second argument `redraw()` is a function call to `redraw()` which gets the return value after executing `redraw()` and passed it as second argument to `sort_array`.
3. The third argument is the value `main_grid.bubble_list`

Now lets see the function `sort_array`

```
def sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array):
```

So the first argument is a function, second is return value of `redraw` which seems to be None and third one is `main_grid.bubble_list`. So you are not calling the `sort_array` with correct arguments.

## why does this work ?

```
BubbleSort.sort_array(lambda: redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), new_list, main_grid.bubble_list)
```

Here the first one is a function that returns the output of `redraw` function and second and third are values. So if you change signature of `sort_array` to

```
def sort_array(redraw, array, bubble_array):
```

It will work perfectly because call to redraw will call the anonymous function which in turn will run `redraw`. Second and third argument are the way as expected.

To continue using the method

```
def sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array):
```

You will have call it as

```
BubbleSort.sort_array(new_list, lambda: redraw(main_grid.bubble_list), main_grid.bubble_list)
```

#### Sample:

```
def sort_array(array, redraw, bubble_array):
  print (array, redraw, bubble_array)
  redraw()

def redraw(something):
  print (f"Running Reorder with {something}")

sort_array(1, lambda: redraw(2), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did *not* pass `redraw` as a function.  You *called* the function and passed its return value to `sort_array`.  Since you failed to provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't follow the logic to its conclusion, but appears that `redraw` is true to its name: it redraws something, and returns no defined value; `None` is the default.

If you expect to pass `redraw` *not* as a function, but rather as a call with arguments, I suggest that you look up how to do a "closure" in Python.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i will certainly look that up. I have added example which can be ran.